# How to stream and play mp3 audio from http api to node server?

Tags: node.js, audio

I am trying to stream mp3 audio from URL HTTP to my node server. 
I want to play audio on the server without downloading it.

I have tried '***play-sound***' library from npm however, it only allows me to play mp3 files that are on my computer.

**So this works**

```
var player = require("play-sound");
player.play("demo.mp3", function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

**However, this one doesn't**

```
 var player = require("play-sound");
     player.play("https://example.net/audios/test-audio.mp3", function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
       });
```

Comment: What platform?  And, have you considered executing ffplay as a child process and piping data to it via STDIO?

Comment: Okay. How I can do that?